# Convert DOC [HWPFDocument] to pdf [with font, Table and images] using java

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi, hwpf

converting doc file to pdf

I am using the following code :

```
        POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
        Document Pdfdocument = new Document();

        fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(srcFile));
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
        WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(Pdfdocument, new 
        FileOutputStream(targetFile));

        Pdfdocument.open();
        writer.setPageEmpty(true);
        Pdfdocument.newPage();
        writer.setPageEmpty(true);
        String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
        for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
            Pdfdocument.add(new Paragraph(paragraphs[i]));
        }
```

This generates a pdf without formatting and images 
even fonts will be missing.

Since `WordExtractor` uses only text
is there any other way to convert with fonts and images.
Convertion form  **doc(`HWPFDocument`) but not on docx**

I have referred these SO links

[Convert doc to pdf using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17826401/6032482)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6210694/6032482

[how to convert doc,docx files to pdf in java programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15636516/6032482)

and many more but found 
they all use WordExtractor .

Note:
I can't use library office
nor
Aspose

Can it be done using:

> ApachePOI
>
> DOCX4j
>
> itext

Comment: I believe it would be your answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6210694/7284669

Comment: see the link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201736/javausing-apache-poi-how-to-convert-ms-word-file-to-pdf>